# What is a better XSL styling method for creating an HTML tag?

Tags: html, xslt, xslt-1.0

I have a fairly simple xsl stylesheet for transforming an xml doc that defines our html into an html format (please don't ask why, it's just the way we have to do it...)

```
<xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:apply-templates/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="HtmlElement">
  <xsl:element name="{ElementType}">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="Attributes"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="Text"/>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="HtmlElement"/>
  </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Attributes">
  <xsl:apply-templates select="Attribute"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Attribute">
  <xsl:attribute name="{Name}">
    <xsl:value-of select="Value"/>
  </xsl:attribute>
</xsl:template>
```

The issue came up when I ran across this little bit of HTML requiring transformation:

```
<p>
      Send instant ecards this season <br/> and all year with our ecards!
</p>
```

the `<br/>` in the middle breaks the logic of the transformation and gives me only the first half of the paragraph block: `Send instant ecards this season <br></br>`.  The XML attempting to be transformed looks like:

```
<HtmlElement>
    <ElementType>p</ElementType>
    <Text>Send instant ecards this season </Text>
    <HtmlElement>
      <ElementType>br</ElementType>
    </HtmlElement>
    <Text> and all year with our ecards!</Text>
</HtmlElement>
```

Suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply add a new rule for Text elements and then match both HTMLElements and Texts:

```
<xsl:template match="HtmlElement">
  <xsl:element name="{ElementName}">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="Attributes"/>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="HtmlElement|Text"/>
  </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Text">
    <xsl:value-of select="." />
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Now how will this affect, say, an `<i>...</i>` tag?  I'm not sure I understand where you're going with this answer

Comment: @CallMeTroggy Well, first of all, this XSL produces the HTML output you wanted given the XML input you specified in the question. So that should be something ;) It will also work perfectly fine with any nested HTML elements as long as they follow the XML structure you laid out in the question - just try it out!

Comment: Ah-ha!  Yes, this was exactly what I needed.  I'm still relatively new to XSL, I hadn't really seen/understood what the pipe does (still a bit unsure, but a better grasp now).  Thanks @phihag!

Answer (score 0):

You could make the stylesheet a bit more generic in order to handle additional elements by adjusting the template for `HtmlElement` to ensure that it applies templates first to the `Attributes` element, and then to all elements ***except for*** the `Attributes`  and `HtmlElement` elements by using a predicate filter in the select attribute of the `xsl:apply-templates`.

The built-in templates will match the `Text` element and will copy the `text()` to the output.

Also, the template for the root node that you currently have declared (i.e. `match="/"`) can be removed. It simply re-defines what is already handled by the built-in template rules and does not do anything to change behavior, just clutters your stylesheet.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0"> 
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>

<!--    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:template>-->

    <xsl:template match="HtmlElement">
        <xsl:element name="{ElementType}">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="Attributes"/>
            <!--apply templates to all elements except for ElementType and Attributes-->
            <xsl:apply-templates select="*[not(self::Attributes|self::ElementType)]"/>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="Attributes">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="Attribute"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="Attribute">
        <xsl:attribute name="{Name}">
            <xsl:value-of select="Value"/>
        </xsl:attribute>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```